# The if and elif questions are always skipped reguardless of the input

Tags: python

heres the code:

```
L = '?'
ignore_letters = ['!','?','.',',']
print("type 'commands' for list of commands")
name = input('hello what is your name :) ')
def main():
    global restart
    answer = input('please type your request here '+name+': ')
    def answer():
        global answer
        if 'list' in [answer] and 'take' in [answer]:
            print('ok')
            i = input('type your list '+name+' ')
            l = i.split()
            global L
            L = l.sort()
            main()
        elif 'run' in [answer] and 'list' in [answer]:
            print('ok sure')
            print('here ' + L )
            main()
```

(this code is only a part of the line of code but I think the issue should be in here)

I also tried the answers with other types of brackets around answer and with none just to be sure it wasnt that

I'm kinda new to coding so I feel like its something wrong with my code that I don't see

Comment: well, for starters, you re-assign `answer` to your function you define... i.e. `answer = input('please type your request here '+name+': ')` then `def answer(): ...`...

Answer (score 2):

You are incorrectly using the `global` keyword in your code.

Note:
**The global keyword is used to change or create global variables from a non-global scope, e.g. inside a function.**

Consider the code,

```
def funcA():
    varA = 20
    def funcB():
        global varA
        varA = 25

    funcB()
    print(varA)

funcA()
```

When you execute the above code the output will be `20` despite the value of `varA` is changed in `funcB`. What essentialy happening is that you have created a global variable named `varA` and assigned it to value `25` but when you are calling `print(varA)` its referring to local variable declared inside `funcA`.

To solve this problem, you have to use `nonlocal` keyword,
The nonlocal keyword is used to work with variables inside nested functions, where the variable should not belong to the inner function.

Consider the code,

```
def funcA():
    varA = 20
    def funcB():
        nonlocal varA
        varA = 25

    funcB()
    print(varA)

funcA()
```

Now, when you execute the code the output will be `25` as expected.

---

Now, coming to your code, the correct code might look like,

```
L = '?'
ignore_letters = ['!', '?', '.', ',']
print("type 'commands' for list of commands")
name = input('hello what is your name :) ')


def main():
    global restart
    answer = input('please type your request here ' + name + ': ').split()

    def answerFunc():
        nonlocal answer
        if 'list' in answer and 'take' in answer:
            print('ok')
            i = input('type your list '+name+' ')
            l = i.split()
            global L
            L = l.sort()
            main()
        elif 'run' in answer and 'list' in answer:
            print('ok sure')
            print('here ' + L)
            main()

    answerFunc()
```

Comment: i just tried that but what happend is it said the list object is not callable